# NetBeans IDE - How do i make indent lines, where i have largest and longest if while for brakets, can not find start and end now

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-7

I have my `Java/C` code running in NetBeans IDE. Where i have some mess algorithms which is like largest/longest something like following:

```
if () { 
 while() {
   for() { 
   }
 }
} elseif( ) {
 for() {
   while() { 
     for() {
     }
   }
 }
} elseif( ) {
 do {
  for () {  
    if() { 
    } else { 
    }
  }
 } while() ; 
} elseif( ) {
  switch() {
   if(a.starsWith()) { 
    for() {
     do {
      for() {
       if() {
       } elseif() {
       } else { 
         switch() {  }
       }
      }
     } while();            
    }
   }
  } 
} elseif( ) {
} elseif( ) {
} elseif( ) {
}
```

Therefore, to find out how do i get this following type of indent highlighted lines?

[image]

Comment: The asker means the soft indent lines like the ones [Reddit uses](http://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/comments/u7551/teen_solves_newtons_300yearold_riddle_an/). As far as I know Netbeans does not offer these as of 7.1, or at least in any logical option that I can see. I would love for this to be an optional feature.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure what your question is, and the image you attached is too small:-(

Anyways, you can specify the type of indent you want NetBeans to use for your code in Preferences -> Editor -> Formatting. You can choose the indents to be tabs, or (recommended) spaces. There is a box where you type in the number of spaces you want per tab.

Also, you can make NetBeans format the code automatically for you, under Source -> Format.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Correct. But i mean those lines: td has closing td tr has closing tr with soft lines on it: http://ostatic.com/files/images/Notepad++(1).jpg

Comment: Do you mean how to get this type of indenting - each tag in a separate line? Like I said, NetBeans formats your code based on your settings in Preferences -> Editor -> Formatting. You can choose tabs or soft tabs there, among other things. And pressing Return after each tag will move it to the new line with indentation. If you want to indent tags manually, there's a shortcut for it: Ctrl + Shift +  Left or Right arrow. Did you try Source -> Format?

Comment: Source format i tried i do that always after rough code to fresh code based on my IDE setting. But i mean completely different thing "there is a line if you have used notepad++" that one.

Answer (score 2):

The vertical lines you see in Notepad++ are not available in NetBeans. But I didn't try the new NetBeans 7.2 beta yet...

Answer (score 0):

From version of Netbeans 8.0 indent lines are available out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

In netbeans 8.1 tools>options>Fonts&Colors>Category>Indent Guide Lines then change Forground to your likeing.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking to highlight lines or just indent your code correctly?

If it is the latter, select all your code, then from the menu bar select Source -> Format.

That should resolve the issue.